# Database backup using PGP

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 11 and postgre in my local machine. I want to write a program in PGP to dump all of the data from the table to a .csv file. For example, if I have table name `table1`.

After running the program a csv file(after zip) will be generated with timestamp.

```
mytable.YYYYMMDDHHMISS.csv.gz
```

I am new to PGP, is there any link or example I can look at please?

Comment: PGP is an encryption program. Doesn't have anything to do with your task.

Comment: Hi mat, thanks for your reply. I might have asked a wrong question here. Forget about the PGP at this point, if I want to just backup table from my database into csv files. What is the best way please?

Comment: So which one is it, Oracle or PostgreSQL? Those are two different database systems.